# has anyone comes with new solution for codeigniter and uploadify session problem

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, uploadify

i know that this is a famous question and have been asked many times. but i want to ask if there is any new solution for uplodify and codeigniter  problem when we use codeigniter session library. i know that flash doesn't forward browser cookies with its request. and i saw many solutions to send the session data as a parameter with uploading request. but it doesn't seems a real solutions for me.

any help ?

Comment: real solution? it's what your browser is doing with cookies so it doesn't seem _that_ out of the realm of reason to communicate with flash that way..

Comment: @Dan ... it's a known bug in flash that it only sends IE cookies with the request. so if the browser is not IE no cookies will be sent to the server.

Comment: Yeah - i was talking more 'in principle' of cookie/session operation.. but the short is you have to do the work of session management with those kind of systems... though html5's uploading via drag 'n drop is looking pretty bitchin'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In application/config/config.php**

Set this to false:

```
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
```

This will prevent codigniter from attempting to match the Useragent (since flash uses a different useragent to the browser).